# Numpy append() appends `\\\\\` into my array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, append

I'm using numpy append() function to append certains values from a .csv file as long as the file is read. The problem is that as it happens, somehow inverted slashes (`\\\`) are added into it.
I don't know why is it happening, i will paste some code behind here.

This is how the array looks after some iterations while debugging. Also the requirement that i need to the meters to be added into the array is mts >= x :

`'[\'[\\\'[\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'["[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'130\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']" \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'60\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'100\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'62\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'70\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\'\\\\n \\\\\\\'55\\\\\\\']\\\'\\n \\\'50\\\']\'\n \'90\']'`

The code is the following:

`

```
        cont = 0
        arr = [] RESULTS
        prc = [] # PRICES
        metros = [] #SQUARED FEET OF PROPERTIES  ----HERE IS THE PROBLEM----
        for row in reader:
            if row['tipo_propiedad'] == propiedad and row['ambientes'] == cant_amb and row['m2'] >=                                 sqmts:
                arr = np.append(arr, [row[''], row['url']]) ##SE OBTIENE EL NUMERO DE FILA Y LA URL DE LAS COINCIDENCIAS
                prc = str(np.append(prc, row['precio']))
                metros = str(np.append(metros, row['m2'])) #IN MY CASE SHOWN ABOVE, IF M2 >= 100 IT SHOULD BE ADDED TO THE ARR
                cont += 1  ##COUNTER
```

`

SUPPOSING CSV M2 FILE WOULD BEEN '100','120','80','130'
OUTPUT SHOULD HAVE BEEN ['100','120','130']

EDIT: .CSV FILE SHARED [GOOGLE DRIVE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12J9mHuq_V4rfyuDzizbGzLZmAz-xsJL1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share what file of data you're using?

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer just did it, thanks

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]. This must be *self contained*.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  You seem to pointlessly initializes `prc` and metros` with a list. But then, in the body of the loop, you assign a string representation of a numpy array to those variables (discarding whatever was there before). Why are using the `str` representation of the numpy arrays? What is the **output** you expect given an example set of *inputs*.

Comment: Why are you using `np.append` to work with a list? `arr = []`?

Comment: Do not treat `np.append` like a clone of the list append.  Even when it works, it is slower.  It's a crude cover for `np.concatenate`, and adds little, unless you need to add one element to a 1d array.  `metros` starts as a list; `np.append` will make it an array.  Don't mix and match lists and arrays mindlessly.

Comment: This code needs to be rewritten using proper list methods (no np.appends)